# Nape event when ready?

Tags: actionscript-3, nape

Is there a way to check/listen for the simulation to be ready ? I'm using a lot of objects so the scene and the engine take time to init. Is there an event in Nape that is dispatched when its ready ? Dispatching at the end of my init scene function (where I add the bodies to Nape) doesn't do it. Any idea ? Cheers.

Comment: The question seems rather vague. I never knew Nape had an event for initialization?

Comment: Personally i dispatch an event at the end of my init function and all is good. What exactly is your problem ? do you have errors ?

Comment: I have so many bodies that at the end of my nape init function, if i dispatch, nape isn't done init'ing its space. So I get the event that's it's ready but it's not, I still have to wait a bit until the simulation is really ready : I check my MS / FPS counter and Nape will  need a few more seconds before my FPS is back to 60 and MS at full speed after the end of the init phase...